# R loop dataframe and create a vector from each row

Tags: r, loops

New to R. I am trying to create a vector from each row in a dataframe, and name the vector after the position in the dataframe. Sample data:

```
 a <- read.table(text='keyword1     keyword2
  1     "hello"     "goodbye"
  2     "foo"     "y"', header=TRUE)
```

each row should become a character string like:

```
name1 <- c("hello", "goodbye")
name2 <- c("foo", "y")
```

I'm thinking something like this, but its not quite there:

```
for (i in 1:length(a)) {
name <- a[i,1];
names <- c(name, a[i,2]);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option

```
foo <- function(i) sapply(unname(a), as.character)[i,]

list2env(
    setNames(Map(foo, 1:nrow(a)), gsub("keyword", "name", names(a))),
    .GlobalEnv
)

name1
# [1] "hello"   "goodbye"
name2
# [1] "foo" "y"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach:

```
> rows <- sapply(1:2, function(i) strsplit(paste(a[i,1], a[i,2]), " "))
> names(rows) <- c("name1", "name2")
> list2env(rows, envir = .GlobalEnv)
# let's see the output:
> name1
[1] "hello"   "goodbye"
> name2
[1] "foo" "y"
```